# Java annotation: elements declared as method but value set as attribute

Tags: java, annotations

When we create a custom annotation, we declare elements as methods and later set values as if they were attributes.

For example, here we have declared a custom annotation `ComponentType` with elements `name()` and `description()` that look like methods.

```
public @interface ComponentType {
    String name();// declared as method
    String description();
}
```

When the annotation is used, they look like the below:

```
@ComponentType(name = "userContainer", // value looks like an attribute
               description = "a user container")
public class UserEntity { }
```

**My question is**: Why doesn't Java allow to declaring elements as attributes, like this?

```
public @interface ComponentType {
    String name; // Compilation Error
    String description;
}
```

Comment: It's a design choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the properties of an annotation weren't *defined* as abstract methods in an interface, they would have been members. Something like:

```
public @interface ComponentType {
    String name;
    String description;
}
```

However, all the members in an interface are implicitly `final` (and `static`) and the above code does not compile, because `name` and `description` aren't initialized.

But if they were actually initialized with some values:

```
public @interface ComponentType {
    String name = "name";
    String description = "description";
}
```

then snippets like the following one wouldn't have been possible:

```
@ComponentType(
  name = "userContainer" //cannot assign a value to a final variable 
, description = "a user container")
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

***My observation is:***

Java consider **annotations** as special type of **interface** so:

1. Like interface we can declare only final attributes in an annotation:

   ```
   String appName = "test application";//final attribute, never reset value
   ```
2. Annotation may contains only abstract methods(a method that is declared without an implementation).

   ```
   public @interface ComponentType {
     String name();// declared as abstract method
   ```
3. When we annotated elements(e.g. class, method, attribute) by annotation we need to set return value of those abstract methods, ***which looks like attribute but actually acts as an implementation.***

   ```
   @ComponentType(name = "userContainer"//set return value of method name()
   ```
4. We can use the values we set during annotated elements(e.g. class, method, attribute) by simply calling abstract methods of annotation.

   ```
   Annotation annotation = annotatedClassObject.getAnnotation(ComponentType.class);
   ComponentType componentType = (ComponentType) annotation;
   String someName = componentType.name(); //returns value set during annotating
   ```

So like as **interface**,

- Annotation never support to declare any **non-final** attributes.
- Annotation may contains some **abstract methods** and we need to set return value of
  abstract method during annotated elements(e.g. class, method,
  attribute).

> **Expecting More Feedback / Answer**

Comment: You're observations are correct and they pretty much summarize my answer. :)